# Dialog to pick a file name like in the "Save As" dialog in Photoshop script

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

Is there an API to show a dialog that allows the user to browse/create folders and either pick an already existing file or enter the name for a new one in order to save some metadata.

Something like the "Save As" dialog in Photoshop but without actually saving anything, but just retrieve the path and filename entered by the user.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a specific API, but is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

```
var inFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Please select folder to process");
if (inFolder != null)
{
    var fileList = inFolder.getFiles(/\.(png)$/i);
}
```

or

```
 var filterFiles = 'CSV:*.csv'; // I am windows
 theFile = File.openDialog ("Choose the CSV file to load from" , filterFiles);
```

Whereas you can reference theFile or fileList to get the file or path you're after.

Comment: I think the second option is what I'm looking for, but I still need a field where to put the name for the new file, in case that I don't want to overwrite some other file. I added a screenshot with what I get with the second option. Thanks.

Comment: In that case I'd be inclined to create a dialogue box with the [Photoshop UI Script](https://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5.pdf)